# ElasticSearch: Labelling documents with matching search term

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 1.7 and am in need of a way to label documents with what part of a query_string query they match.

I've been experimenting with highlighting, but found that it gets a bit messy with some cases. I'd love to have the document tagged with matching search terms.

Here is the query that I'm using: ( note this is a ruby hash that later gets encoded to JSON )

```
{
  query: {
    query_string: {
      fields: ["title^10", "keywords^4", "content"],
      query: query_string,
      use_dis_max: false
    }
  },
  size: 20,
  from: 0,
  sort: [
    { pub_date: { order: :desc }},
    { _score:   { order: :desc }}
  ]
}
```

The `query_string` variable is based off user followed topics and might look something like this: `"(the AND walking AND dead) OR (iphone) OR (video AND games)"`

Is there any option I can use so that documents returned would have a property matching a search term like `the walking dead` or `(the AND walking AND dead)`

Comment: Do you have the option of separating the top-level OR queries into multi `bool/should` sub-queries?

Comment: I initially was using a bool query with should sub queries. However there are some users who follow 50+ topics and so the JSON query was becoming quite large and was slowing things down. Especially cause I'd need 3 queries per term ( to check each field ).

Comment: If I were to switch to using bool/should ( just did some tests that seem like its still relatively quick with a large number of subqueries ). How would this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're ready to switch to using `bool/should` queries, you can split the match on each field and use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html), then in the results you'll get the name of the query that matched.

It goes basically like this: in a `bool/should` query, you add one `query_string` query per field and name the query so as to identify that field (e.g. `title_query` for the `title` field, etc)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "title^10"
            ],
            "query": "query_string",
            "use_dis_max": false,
            "_name": "title_query"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "keywords^4"
            ],
            "query": "query_string",
            "use_dis_max": false,
            "_name": "keywords_query"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "content"
            ],
            "query": "query_string",
            "use_dis_max": false,
            "_name": "content_query"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the results, you'll then get below the `_source` another array called `matched_queries` which contains the name of the query that matched the returned document.

```
"_source": {
    ...
},
"matched_queries": [
    "title_query"
],
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted.