# Elasticsearch - how to know if a particular match condition was hit

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello elastic experts!

I am new to elasticsearch. I am trying to build a search query with multiple `or` matching. I am boosting the query for different matching conditions. But here I need a bit more information. I need to know which conditions contributed to the search result. Is there any way to know which match conditions were hit by the query string?

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
    {
      "term": {
        "title.keyword": {
          "value": "Ski trip",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "match_phrase_prefix": {
        "title": {
          "query": "Ski trip",
          "boost": 0.8
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "title": {
          "query": "Ski trip",
          "operator": "and",
          "boost": 0.6
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "description": {
          "query": "Ski trip",
          "boost": 0.3
        }
      }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836381/elasticsearch-labelling-documents-with-matching-search-term/35883085#35883085

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot :-)